# How to Institiate an object in when we have pure virtual function hirerachy?

Tags: c++, function, initialization, virtual

```
class A{
    public: virtual void getName() = 0;
};

class B: public A{
    public:
        B(int a){
            cout<< "B Name : " << a <<endl;
        }
        void getName() override { cout << "Class B" << endl; }
};

class C: public B{
    public:
      C(int a){
            cout<< "C Name : " << a <<endl;
        }
        void getName() override { cout << "Class C" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    B *b = new B(10);
    b->getName();

    C *c = new C(20);
    c->getName();
}
```

I am trying to create the object of Class `B` and `C`.but it gives me that error of

```
main.cpp:31:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘B::B()’
       C(int a){
               ^
main.cpp:22:9: note: candidate: B::B(int)
         B(int a){
         ^
```

can anyone explain to me why is that happening? why it is not creating the class object?

Comment: Also unrelated: please make those single-argument constructors `explicit`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue has nothing to do with `virtual` functions.

You have to specify which constructor of `B` should be used to initialize the base subobject `B` in [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) explicitly, otherwise, the default constructor of `B` would be used but `B` doesn't have one. (Note that `B` has a user-defined constructor taking `int` then default constructor won't be generated for `B`.)

> For members that cannot be default-initialized, such as members of reference and const-qualified types, member initializers must be specified.

e.g.

```
C(int a) : B(a) {
//       ^^^^^^
    cout<< "C Name : " << a <<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem doesn't have anything to do with the abstractness of any parent class, it's because your `C` constructor tries to initialize the parent `B` class through the `B` *default constructor*, which it doesn't have any.

You need to "call" the parameterized `B` constructor through the constructor initializer list

```
C(int a)
    : B(a)  // "Calls" the B constructor
{
}
```

Optionally add a default constructor to the `B` class.

Answer (score 2):

```
B(int a){
        cout<< "B Name : " << a <<endl;
    }
```

When you construct `C`, `B` also needs to be constructed. If you do not specify how to intialize sub class (through initializer list specifying the constructor to be called), base is default constructed which requires a default constructor.

Since you defined a constructor for `B` class, there is no default constructor generated for `B`. You could either define a default constructor for `B` or specify `B(int a)` to be used through initializer list.

Note that you could create object of `B` without specifying constructor for base `A` since `A` class has a default constructor generated which is used.